# Bug in the Merge Tags UI

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators, tag-merge-utility

So, I noticed that there is a [visualstudio] tag that should probably be merged into the sponsored [visual-studio] tag.

I clicked my happy ** to the Tag Merge page and followed the directions on the screen:

[image: pre merge]

The UI seems to be pretty clear on what will happen to each tag.  The first is the Master into which the second will be merged (renamed/removed).

But when I hit Preview Merge, I was told I'm a moron who can't read:

[image: Idiot!]

At this point, I shut down my computer and ran away.  I think something is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page always confused me ... I went ahead and simplified

[image: new ui]

Simple, there is old, there is new ... old will be gone (if it exists), new will be created.

Answer (score 5):

[visualstudio](/questions/tagged/visualstudio) doesn't exist on Stack Overflow except as a synonym of [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio). You might see it in the tags page, but it's still only a synonym.

As such, you're specifying a blank tag as the rename tag. The righthand sidebar (which admittedly, is far off to the right, so it is easy to overlook), has the following to say about this:

> If the Remove Tag does not exist, the Master Tag will be *renamed* to the Remove Tag (which will exist after the merge).

Hence why the heading of that box is "Remove / **Rename** Tag". Specifying blank tags is how we do a mass tag rename as opposed to a standard mass tag merge.

Comment: That... that is stupid.  While I admit I cannot read, that has got to be... I think I threw up a little in my mouth.  These two completely different functions should **NOT** be combined within the same UI.  If it wasn't for the fact that I was paying attention, I would have completely renamed the [visual-studio] tag.  Holy crap, that's bad UI design.  Wow.

Comment: @Will You could suggest that as its own feature-request, then. I imagine the current state is simply to maintain that the Master Tag *must* exist.

Comment: Will do.

Answer (score 1):

> **[visualstudio](/questions/tagged/visualstudio) doesn't exist on Stack Overflow except as a synonym of [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)**. You might see it in the tags page, but it's still only a synonym.

What he said.

Why wasn't this clear to you? That's the real problem, not the rename / merge UI.

(we can probably have this page check to see if someone is mistaking a synonym for an actual tag and block it.)

Comment: It wasn't clear because it wasn't clear.  Renaming a tag and merging two tags are two completely different operations and should not be combined within the same UI.  What if I wanted to merge two tags and the Merge/Rename tag does not exist?  I should be warned "hey, dopey, that tag doesn't exist."  What if I wanted to rename a tag and the target name exists?  I should be warned "Moron, you can't rename that; a tag with the new name already exists."  As it currently stands, my attempts to do something wrong will be treated as if I validly meant to do something else.

Comment: @will we will definitely block synonyms in the tool, that's a good suggestion.