# Please break the [tag-merge] → [retag-request] synonym

Tags: feature-request, meta, tag-synonyms

On the one hand, merge requests are the same as retag-requests. So it makes sense that questions asking about tags to be merged should get [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request).

However, [there are also questions about the tag merge utility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87999/bug-in-the-merge-tags-ui). [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) is itself a synonym of [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), which makes sense because questions about retagging practices can be simplified as questions about tags. The same cannot be said about merging, which is a bigger subject than what [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) conveys.

Could we break the synonym? Maybe instate a [tag-merge-request](/questions/tagged/tag-merge-request) tag that is synonymized with [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request), that way people who initially think of tagging a merge request with the merging tag will see the request option. As it stands, even if we provide an alternate tag like, say, [merge-tags](/questions/tagged/merge-tags), people will still see tag-merge in the suggestions when asking about the merge utility, so it'll just inspire a greater ease in picking the wrong tag.

Comment: This should be closed, as it specifically pertains to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro it's really too old to care. There are thousands of these.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: I don't know if you noticed, but MSE, the site we are on, still has the precise synonym arrangement described. So *no*, it has nothing to do with SO specifically.

Comment: This was asked when this site *was* MSO and as Nathan points out is still relevant so there's absolutely no reason to close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't agree.

The questions about the merge utility are ultra-rare and aberrant -- not to mention *only visible to diamond moderators* -- and should have another tag like [merge-utility](/questions/tagged/merge-utility) or something. (In addition to the [moderator-tools](/questions/tagged/moderator-tools) tag, probably)

Comment: Alright, let's see how that rolls. I still expect that there will be some erroneous retagging, but as merge utility questions are indeed rarer in frequency, perhaps that's just a risk we can take.

Comment: @grace to be clear, I realize the UI is pretty sucky on that tool, but it's just not a mainstream topic of discussion and it's relevant to so few.

Comment: I understand (and personally, I don't mind the UI but I'm something of an automaton when it comes to webforms). After you mentioned that point, I did some research on Meta to discover that indeed, there are very few discussions on the tool itself.