# Layout improvement for "Create Tag Synonym"

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms, moderator-tools

In normal spoken language, you would say *"pot" is a synonym for "kettle";* you would state the source first and then the target. 
But the page to create tag synonyms has the text-entry fields the other way 'round, and I caught myself filling it in wrong before submitting it - this time. This is the wrong order, IMHO.

There's plenty of whitespace, so it shouldn't be a problem to have the two fields next to each other instead. It would be even better with an "→" arrow in between, or perhaps something more verbal than just the two field headings.

[image: layout suggestion]

Comment: Why can't we do the same thing for the tag *synonym* UI that [we did for the tag *merge* UI](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88945/153008)?

Comment: I agree that the order seems backwards, but I don't know how having them next to each other helps, and it doesn't really match the rest of the UI