# Please make the tag synonym tool less confusing

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, moderator-tools

This is the screen for creating tag synonyms (Arqade edition):

[image]

Which is source and which is target? Every time I use this tool I get confused, as either way could theoretically make sense. The language used in all other tag-synonym contexts is **Master** and **Synonym**. Please can this page be made to match this convention too?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128956/layout-improvement-for-create-tag-synonym

Comment: Should be something like "merge [tag] permanently into [other tag]" or "Replace [tag] with [tag]  Please note: the tag being replaced is merged into the second tag and will no longer be used."

Comment: @Won't This is for creating synonyms, not merges, that's a different tool.

Comment: ... ... yeah but still.